# Does the compiler copy a std::string into stack while passing it to a function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a simple question. I have a long std::string that I want to pass it to a function.
I wanna know that this string will be copy to stack then a copy of that will be passed or something like pointer will be passed and no additional space will be required?

(C++)

- I have another little question: How much memory does an element of a string take?Just like `char`?

Comment: Are you talking about a `std::string`?

Comment: What do you mean by string? Quoted text? std::string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be deep copied, so use const reference is recommended.

```
void fun(const std::string & arg)
```

Typically std::string has 2 fields, a pointer pointing to dynamic allocated memory and the length, so it is 16+actual length on 64bit machines.

Comment: I would expect **3 fields** at minimum: pointer, current length, and max length.

Comment: There is no typical string. MSVC's is fat (but does not allocate dynamic memory for small strings) while gcc's is just a pointer to a ref-counted buffer (and so allocates dynamic memory for even a single `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler Alert: My answer wont be that relevant, just an optimization technique.

If you dont want to duplicate the string, write your customized string class, which has two pointers or one pointer with size. In the past it has reduced me a lot of duplicates. This will work only as read-only and do a copy_on_write, i.e duplicate only if you encounter a write.

Comment: COW is possible for `std::string` as well, but is often slower than copying + small string optimization in practice.

Answer (score 0):

When passing an argument by value in C++ it is conceptually copied. Whether this copy really happens is another question, though, and depends on how the argument is passed and, to some extend, on the compiler: the compiler is explicitly allowed to elide certain copies, in particular copies of temporary objects. For example, when you return an object from a function and it us clear that the object will be returned, the copy is likely to be elided. Similarily, when passing the result of a function directly on to another function, it is likely not to be copied.

Beyond this C++ 2011 added another dimension of possibilities by supporting move constructors. These cover to some extend similar ground but also allow you to have better control: you can explicitly indicate that it would be acceptable for an object to be moved rather than being copied. Still, in no event will an object passed by reference.

With respect to the used bytes per element, the `std::string` uses just `sizeof(cT)` bytes (where `cT` is the character template argument of the `std::basic_string`). However, the string will overallocate the space in many cases and certainly when characters are added to the string. You can determine the overallocation by comparing `size()` and `capacity()` and control it to some extend with `reserve()` although this function isn't required of getting rid of any overallocation but the `capacity()` has to be at least as much as was last `reserve()`d. If the string is small (e.g. at most 15 characters) modern implementations won't make any allocation. This is called the *string optimization*.

With respect to the actual represention of the string:  unless it is small it will use one word for the address of the storage, one word each for the the size and the capacity, and for strings with stateful allocators the size of the allocator (typically another word). Given alignment requirements this effectively means that in most cases the string will take four words in addition to the elements. Typically the small string optimization uses these words to store characters if the string firs there unless, of course, it needs to store a stateful allocator.